# Facebook app cannot be displayed in IE9 only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app. Problem is that it does not load in IE9 (did not test with other versions of IE). It displays the following message when opening the canvas page:

"This content cannot be displayed in a frame
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."

It however works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari.

My canvas page URL and page tab url's are fine, and as I said, it works in all other browsers.

I know the question is vague, but any help would be appreciated. I cannot post my code here, cause it is A LOT of code and has a lot of external files it links to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: http://sscce.org Isolate what you think to be cause of the problem and post relevant code. [We're not mind-readers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/186879). Well, at least most of us aren't.

Comment: Give us the URL to the page you’re trying to load into the iframe, please.

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté - As I said in my question, I have a lot of code and links to external files, and figuring out what may cause it will we hours of work. I cannot give you the link since you can only access the app once you have a registered account with us... I was hoping someone here might know something about this issue from previous experience or something...like the answer below is kinda what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using PHP for the app?
If yes, put this at the top of the code: **header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');** Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am using php, but I link to multiple pages from the main facebook page. Do I need to add this line you gave me in every relevant page containing php? Also, "header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');" ->should it stand just like that, isn't there suppose to be some tags around it or something?

Comment: Try to add it to just one page and, if it works, add it at the top of each PHP page. Yes it stand just like that.

Comment: Nope sorry, does not work for my main page(index.php).Any other suggestions? What is this code suppose to do?

Comment: I gave another shot at it and got it to work.Thank you very much. But What exactly does it do? I hope that it won't break any functionality in any other browsers...But thank you again

Comment: Found it: http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2002/06/p3p_in_ie6_frustrating_failure.html

Comment: Friendly reminder - these aren't arbitrary letters, they mean things that could potentially be legally binding. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2692929/945370