# Facebook iframe issue on Internet Explorer

Tags: facebook, security, internet-explorer, iframe

I have built a fb page tab app (made a couple in the past with no problems as well), but in this one the more recent i have problem with Internet Explorer.

I keep getting this error message—

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame
>
> To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

I already tried this suggested solution with no success -

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
```

I had an issue also with Safari and xdomain which was solved with this header

```
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
```

but the issue on internet explorer remains..i would really appreciate some help

[Facebook app cannot be displayed in IE9 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919056/facebook-app-cannot-be-displayed-in-ie9-only)

Comment: What is the address of the frame that comes up as blocked? Note that `GOFORIT` is invalid and should not be used except as a last-ditch workaround for when the server your app is deployed on adds unwanted headers and you don't have access to stop it doing that. It is not something you should really be relying on for a production service.

Comment: appreciate your comment @bobince can you please advise how to solve this? the url of the frame is this one https://clients.rubicon.gr/developer/Samsung_EuroBasket/form.php

Comment: i did some testing and it seems that on i.e. the app doesn't manage to retrieve the fb_id of the user at all..

Comment: i added the header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); on all pages.. now i.e. works..but safari doesnt..

Comment: Is “Samsung_EuroBasket” your application? On submission `index_mobile.php` does a redirect to a facebook.com page, which naturally refuses to be viewed inside a frame (you can't change that—it's Facebook's policy). All browsers that support `X-Frame-Options` will block that; it seems like Chrome is blocking the navigation rather than displaying an error like IE does, but either way it's broken. Did you mean to do a redirect here?

Comment: yes this is my app..it works normally on chrome and firefox, also mobile and after adding header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); on all pages on i.e. but now it doesn't work on safari no matter if i use header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); or not
index_mobile.php it is just a redirect to recognize if it is mobile version or desktop..normally user wouldn't end to that redirect after form.php

Comment: I don't see `X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT` in the response headers on either the form page or the submission redirect, but it doesn't matter because it is Facebook's page that refuses to be framed, not yours. Why are you redirecting to facebook.com? This fails for me on all browsers. Chrome refuses to navigate, Firefox gives a blank white page, IE gives an error page. The P3P header is also irrelevant to framing, because your page is the framer not the framee.

Comment: i m not redirecting to facebook.com i m redirecting to the page_tab where the app is hosted.. the url that i gave you would actually work only on mobile.. on desktop the access is directly on facebook environment.. redirection takes palce if can't retrieve id

Comment: Well, I get a redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/SamsungMobileGreece/app_487296798007389` when I try to test your page, and that page has `X-Frame-Options: deny`, which when running it in a frame naturally and intentionally breaks. That's about as far as I can go...